# Plotting a transition map in Gnuplot 4.6 (or other softwares?)

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Goodmorning everybody,
I searched in the web for this problem for something like an hour an nobody seemed to have my same difficulty, so here I am. I'll explain you my problem: I have four states (but in future they can become much more the four) A, B, C and D between which a particle can do transitions. Suppose I know exactly how many times the particle undergoes the A->B, B->C, C->D, A->C (... and so on) transitions. I want to represent my states as dots on a circle and the transitions as arrows between states, which are wider (the arrows, not the dots!) proportionally to the number of transitions. I hope I made myself clear. Is this possible on Gnuplot 4.6? Otherwise: do you know other programs able to do that? Because I saw maps like this before, but sincerly I don't even know how to search for them!!

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Making a crappy diagram of what you want to achieve is probably the easiest way to tell you if/how you can do. E.g. draw it by hand, scan it and put a link in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A much more suitable tool for your problem would be [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). You can use the Graphviz “DOT” language to express your transition map directly, and then use the Graphviz tools to perform various types of automated layout (including circular ones) and to produce image files showing the nodes and edges in the graph. If none of the automated layouts are what you want, you can compute them yourself and set the positions explicitly, and still use graphviz's renderer.

Comment: Totally seconding this. gnuplot isn't nearly as suited as graphviz for what you want to do.